# Adding JSON object items to DIVs with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I've looked up a lot of examples and none really answered my question. I'm trying to iterate through a JSON file and add certain items to divs on my page.

Here's the code I've written so far. This code returns all the item values of all objects into the different divs instead of appending each item to its div. You can ignore the first for loop, it's just for adding id's to each div. I've also created an [example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/730L65gv/).

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams',
    dataType: 'json', 
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        var name = document.getElementsByClassName("player-name");
        var gamename = document.getElementsByClassName("gamename");
        var viewcount = document.getElementsByClassName("viewcount");
        var date = document.getElementsByClassName("date");
        var numItems = $('.stream').length;
        var i = 1;

        $('.stream').each(function(i) {
            $(this).attr('id', (i + 1));
            i++;
        });

        $('.stream').each(function(i, obj) {
            $.each(data.streams,function(index,item) {
                $(name).append(item.channel.name);
                $(gamename).append(item.channel.game);
                $(viewcount).append(item.viewers);
                $(date).append(item.created_at);
            });
        });
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("some error");
    }
});
```

Comment: You may have more luck getting a response if you were to clarify your question a bit more and include an example of your data and expected outcome.

Comment: here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/730L65gv/

Each container (class="stream") should get values  name, gamename, viewcount etc. The code in the fiddle gets those elements, but gives each DIV everything it gets, instead of giving each DIV a single value of each wanted item.

Answer (score 0):

```
var name = $(".player-name"); // jQuery's $ cares about your fingers 
var gamename = $(".gamename");
var viewcount = $(".viewcount");
var date = $(".date");

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams',
    dataType: 'json', 
    success: function(data) {

        console.log(data);

        $.each(data.streams,function(index,item) {
            // now use .eq(index) over your elements collections
            name.eq(index).append(item.channel.name);
            gamename.eq(index).append(item.channel.game);
            viewcount.eq(index).append(item.viewers);
            date.eq(index).append(item.created_at);
        });

    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("some error");
    }
});
```

Comment: This solves it! I didn't know how to address the current iteration item,I was missing the eq.(index) part. Thank you very much :)